# Refresh / Repaint SVG in Apache Batik

Tags: java, multithreading, svg, batik

I am using **Apache Batik** to load, manipulate and render an SVG graphic for simulation purposes.
Loading and manipulating works so far, at least when writing the SVG out to a file. Also rendering and updating it ONCE (!) works.

In order to manipulate the SVG, I am creating a org.w3c.dom.svg.SVGDocument and to display it I am using a org.apache.batik.swing.JSVGCanvas.

In the manipulation part, what happens is that e.g. the "style" attribute of an element is retrieved and manipulated by e.g. changing the "fill:#HEX_CODE".

I am able to render the SVG when loading the Java GUI created by IntelliJ using the GridLayoutManager (IntelliJ). Basically, there is a Form, a mainPanel within and a visualizationPanel within that. Panels are all of type JPanel. The visualizationPanel contains my svgCanvas of type JSVGCanvas.

In order to trigger the manipulation and refresh the canvas I created a button. When I click the button, the svgDocument is changed and correctly refreshed in the canvas.

**The question now is: how can I do this multiple times in a row?** The idea is to change the color every second and repaint / refresh the canvas after manipulation. It does not seem to work with Thread.sleep(1000);

Here is the runSimulation() method that is triggered when I click the button:

```
public void runSimulation() {

    Element bodyElement = svgDocument.getElementById("body_");
    String bodyStyleAttribute = bodyElement.getAttribute("style");
    String saturationHexColor = "";
    String newBodyStyleAttribute = "";

    saturationHexColor = simulationDataModel.getSaturationHexColor(70);
    newBodyStyleAttribute = bodyStyleAttribute.substring(0, bodyStyleAttribute.lastIndexOf("fill:#")) + "fill:#" + saturationHexColor + bodyStyleAttribute.substring(bodyStyleAttribute.lastIndexOf("fill:#") + "fill:#".length() + 6);

    svgDocument.getElementById("body_").setAttribute("style", newBodyStyleAttribute);
    simulatorView.getSvgCanvas().getUpdateManager().getUpdateRunnableQueue().invokeLater(runnable);


}
```

The "runnable" variable is defined in the constructor of the View as follows:

```
runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                simulatorView.getSvgCanvas().repaint();
            }
        };
```

I am quite unfamiliar with threading in Java and also with complex GUIs. Maybe you can help me out?

Thanks !